# Is it safe to use ContinueWith as a "finally" operation?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

Consider a piece of code like:

```
private Task<string> Download()
{
    var wc = new WebClient();
    Task<string> backgroundDownload = wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(this.Uri);
    // Make sure the WebClient is disposed no matter what.
    backgroundDownload.ContinueWith((downloadTask) => { wc.Dispose(); });
    return backgroundDownload;
}
```

Can I be certain that the `WebClient.Dispose()` call occurs and that any exception produced is rethrown to the caller as if there was no call to `ContinueWith`?

Can clients observe this `ContinueWith`? (e.g. will later calls to `ContinueWith` remove the Dispose call?)

Comment: Have you tried your code just by adding a Console.WriteLine or MessageBox.Show in *ContinueWith* ?

Comment: Why not just use await?

Comment: Also, if you use await, you can then do a using with wc and create a try/catch block wherever it makes sense to do so.

Comment: @L.B. When it comes to anything threading related I don't trust what happens unless it is explicitly documented. Way too easy to have something "accidentally" work.

Comment: @VoteCoffee: Because ContinueWith more clearly expresses the intent here.

Comment: @BillyONeal That *is* explicitly documented.  That's one the impetuses for await...

Comment: @Peter: What? I don't see any such mention of await or exception behavior in the documentation for `ContinueWith`.

Comment: @BillyONeal `When it comes to anything threading related I don't trust what happens unless it is explicitly documented` So either you search for docs which is not what SO is for, OR you think everything posted here can be trusted without hesitations

Comment: @L.B: I trust other humans, yes.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: @PeterRitchie my "don't see documentation" comment is about ContinueWith, not await

Comment: @BillyONeal Did you look at the documentation for `ContinueWith`?  It's very, very clear on the matter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the code that you have you can be certain that the continuation will be fired regardless of whether or not the code completed successfully, was cancelled, or throws an exception.

The one potential *problem* with the solution that you have is that other continuations can potentially run, before, during, or after the web client is disposed.  If you don't have a problem with other continuations running before this cleanup runs then what you have is fine.  If that's a problem then you'll need to return the continuation, not the original task, but you'll also need to propagate the result (and exceptions/cancellation) correctly.  The use of `async` makes all of this way easier:

```
private async Task<string> Download()
{
    using(var wc = new WebClient())
      return await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(this.Uri);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the continuation will be performed even if a regular exception occurred. However it is less likely to run than a regular finally block in the eventuality of exceptional conditions such as an OutOfMemoryException.

Now I would not try to dispose the webclient. Remember that disposing is an optimization, because native resources will be disposed by the finalizer anyway. The only reason we are disposing is that a finalizer is expensive because it triggers a second GC pass.

But in the order to perform your optimization the system may have to create new threads. Besides you may be prolongating the lifetime of your webclient a lot if the threadpool is filled with long running tasks.

Basically, you have to choose the lesser of two evils and I am not convinced that one less GC run is worth what you're doing. You should consider this decision in the context of your application.